# Passing user's local timezone to celery in django app

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a requirement where i want to show date time in user's local datetime. For which I have added a middleware code in django which gets the local date time from user's session through browser and activate that session.
In my django settings.py I have added the timezone which is by default 'America/New york'

Now I have celery where the database operations are performed asynchronously. But in celery the timezone which I am activating in middleware is not getting through. It is always picking it up from django settings.py file.
If i remove the default timezone setting then it is taking the timezone as 'America/Chicago'.

Below is my code for Middleware

```
# middleware.py
from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        user_timezone = request.GET.get('user_timezone', 'America/New_York')
        request.session['user_timezone'] = user_timezone
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And here is my code for celery task

```
# tasks.py
from celery import Celery, Task
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.utils import timezone

app = Celery('yourapp', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

class TimezoneAwareTask(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get user timezone from session or use a default
        user_timezone = self.get_user_timezone(kwargs.get('session_key'))

        # Set the timezone for the task execution
        timezone.activate(user_timezone)

        try:
             result = super(TimezoneAwareTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
             timezone.deactivate()

        return result

    def get_user_timezone(self, session_key):
        try:
            session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
            return session.get_decoded().get('user_timezone', 'America/New_York')
        except Session.DoesNotExist:
            return 'America/New_York'

app.tasks.register(TimezoneAwareTask())
```

So here the task is going under exception i.e. SessionDoesNotExist and the local timezone of the user can't be fetched.